# How to use Query() to generate subtotal group by a column under the Query() result?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am wondering if there are smart and elegant ways to create subtotal below a query result in using Google Sheets' query() function.

Referring to the image below, if I have **DATA** with Currency values, can I generate a table with subtotal based on currency using Query() or some forms of combined Query()?

The challenge is that the number of rows and number of currencies are dynamic in **DATA**. To use query to generate **Report A** is not hard as shown but I just cannot think of a smart way using formulas (instead of App Scripts or pivot table) to create **Report B** when number of currencies is dynamic.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(A3:C3,unique(tocol(B4:B,1)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,filter(A:C,B:B=c),hstack("Subtotal",c,sumif(B:B,c,C:C)))))
```

- *you can use conditional formatting to highlight the `Subtotal` rows just in case*

[image]

Comment: Amazing and creative way to use Reduce() with vstack()! Unfortunately my data are actually not stored in cells but generated by query (sorry I simplified my situation in the initial question). I suppose I can open a new sheet and store the generated data in the sheet and apply your method. However, wonder if there is a way to  summarise without referencing columns within the filter. That would be truly awesome.

Comment: Please share a test sheet recreating this scenario and I can check it out...