# calculating sub-totals for groups of rows in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have rows of product data which are grouped by group names. I want to calculate the subtotal of the prices for products in each group. The number of products in each group is not known or may change.

I applied the subtotal function, set the code to 9 (sum), and selected a range of records. This produced the correct result. My problem is that I want a function which I can copy down on all rows, and which will identify the correct rows to be summed by their shared group value.

Comment: Would you please supply some sample data **AND** an example of a successful outcome. Please do not supply a snapshot but include as text within your question. There are may ways to create  markdown tables including the free online service at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U1b-EfBJuIvKtsb6QPwnYFodqyr5gtr2-Wo__MHQFus/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry, markdown exceeded comment size limit

Comment: If `Sheet1` tab (in your shared sheet) is the Input data, Can you **manually** enter your expected output in `Sheet2` so that it gives a clear picture on what is really expected?

Comment: `sorry, markdown exceeded comment size limit` No worries; the idea was to edit the question, in which case that limit doesn't apply. Just as you would edit the question to include the link to your spreadsheet.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow I_think_ (but couldn't say for sure) that the subtotals are shown in the "Price Display" column (Column F). The difference between this and Column E (Gross) is moot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Query() to generate subtotal group by a column under the Query() result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76701668/how-to-use-query-to-generate-subtotal-group-by-a-column-under-the-query-resu)

Comment: Related question: [How to use dynamic array formula to filter and format data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74020151/1330560).

Comment: Regarding your sample data, are you saying that the "total" rows already exist in the raw data?

Answer (score 0):

Raw data includes "Product groups" and "Display prices" columns. The goal is to `dynamically` generate sub-totals for "Display prices" by "Product group".

Let's assume that the raw data is in the range A1:F10. Enter this formula in cell H1:

```
={ 
  lambda( 
    data, groups, headers, totalsHeader, blankRow, selectPrice, 
    reduce( 
      headers, query(unique(groups), "where Col1 is not null", 0), 
      lambda( 
        resultTable, filterKey, 
        { 
          resultTable; 
          lambda( 
            filterData, 
            { 
              filterData; 
              { totalsHeader, query(filterData, selectPrice, 0) }
            } 
          )(filter(data, groups = filterKey)) 
        } 
      ) 
    ) 
  )( 
    A2:F, 
    A2:A, 
    A1:F1, 
    {"","Total:","","",""}, 
    { "","","","","",""}, 
    "select sum(Col6) label sum(Col6) '' " 
  ) 
}
```

This formula is based on the answer by @doubleunary in [How to use dynamic array formula to filter and format data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74020151/1330560)

---

**Results**

[image: results]

**Raw data**

[image: raw data]

Comment: Thank you. I apologize my sample data sheet was not very clear, and has been updated to include BEFORE and AFTER tabs. Please would you revise your answer? Meanwhile, I will look at the reference you provided and lambda functions, which are new to me.

Comment: `which are new to me` LOL, join the club :)